# Logarithm with nth root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I made it but the result is very strange. I want every step to the result

$$
\large 6\log_{10}\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt5}}
$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I resolve that logarithm?

Comment: It is a question of a test to enter in University. That logarithm is equal to?

Comment: 1. Why all down votes? 2. In order to receive some guidance you ought to show what you learned think of logarithms and explain your problem. 3. Also, the question should have a *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the question is how to expand the logarithm.  Note that
$$
6 \log_{10}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt[3]{3 + \sqrt{5}}} \right) =\\
6 \log_{10}(\sqrt 2) - 6 \log_{10}(\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt 5}) =\\
6 \log_{10}(2^{1/2}) - 6 \log_{10}((3+\sqrt 5)^{1/3})=\\
6 \cdot \frac 12 \log_{10}2 - 6 \cdot \frac 13\log_{10}(3+\sqrt 5) =\\
3 \log_{10}2 - 2\log_{10}(3+\sqrt 5)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternate approach from the first answer:
$$
\begin{split}
6\log_{10}\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt5}}
 &= \log_{10} \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt5}}\right)^6\\
 &= \log_{10}\frac{2^3}{\left(3+\sqrt5\right)^2} \\
 &= \log_{10}\frac{8}{14 + 6\sqrt5} \\
 &= \log_{10}\frac{4}{7 + 3\sqrt5} \\
 &= \log_{10}\frac{4}{7 + 3\sqrt5} \frac{}{7-3\sqrt5} \\
 &= \log_{10}\frac{4(7-3\sqrt5)}{49 - 45} \\
 &= \log_{10}(7-3\sqrt5)
\end{split}
$$